# Displaying colored borders on input elements (form fields) in IE7 and IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, border

I'm using the [jQuery Validation Engine](http://posabsolute.github.com/jQuery-Validation-Engine/) to validate some form fields. Everything's working well except in IE7 and IE8.

The style sheet has a :focus class, which gives them a blue box-shadow when the form field is focussed on:

```
input:focus { outline: none; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px #06c !important; -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #06c; box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #06c; }
```

I'm using jQuery to add a class to the form fields when they're not valid (as defined by the jQuery Validation Engine,) so that those fields can have a red box-shadow:

```
input.error { outline: none; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px #c00 !important; -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #c00; box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #c00; }
```

This works great...in IE9, Firefox, and Chrome. It doesn't work in IE8 or 7. (There was a party when we stopped supporting IE6.) I tried installing PIE.htc and adding a style option that indicated a border for those elements, rather than a box-shadow, but that didn't seem to help and it caused some other display weirdness with the error-bubbles, so I removed PIE.htc. Then I tried having a separate style definition, enclosed in IE-conditional tags, that specified borders for those inputs, but still it didn't work. Here's my conditional-CSS:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">
input:focus { border: 1px solid #06c; }
input.error { border: 1px solid #c00; }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

...help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not everything is supported in those browsers. Just live with it and find an alternative, like showing an additional message. Or you could embed the input element inside a div:

```
​div.invalid {
    display: inline-block; 
    border: 1px solid red;
}​

<div class="invalid">
        <input type="text"/>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

If you start adding element like this, I would do that though JQuery too, and preferably in a separate piece of code that is included only in IE7 and 8, so you can easily drop it once you don't need it anymore. Or you could choose to always use the div, and just style `div.invalid input{...}` for other browsers.

Comment: The jQuery Validation Engine adds a div above the invalid form fields already, to display the tooltip...I don't know if it would be simpler to use jQuery to add the div around the form field, or not. I'll have to defer that question to someone more versed in jQuery than I am, who can get this working, if that's what they decide to go with. (I'm still really hoping to find some kind of a CSS solution, if it's there; but I'll keep this alternative in mind.)

Comment: You could choose to always have the div in the documents and only add the class if a validation error arises. That will add a little extra weight to the document, but both styling and programming may be easier (depending on how much JQuery validation will easily let you modify this div in case of a failed validation).

Comment: Oh, and then use CSS specificity? Er...hm. No, the class would need to be added to the container-div, not to the erroneous input field. So there might be some stickiness there to work around, in that we don't want the error-message tooltip to display in the wrong location and I don't know if adding a DIV around the input fields will cause that to happen. But I'll give it a shot. Can't hurt to try out... Thanks!

Comment: I've got a follow-up for you. I've tested out manually adding the tag, to see how it works. How do I write the style so that the div around the input element displays only when the input element is focussed upon? (I've been trying something similar for select fields in Chrome, but I'm having the problem of not getting the highlight behavior to work the way I want it to. I'm trying to emulate Google Wallet's functionality, with the form fields' being outlined whenever they are focussed on, or flagged as non-validating.)